# Endpoint creation doesn't work in Azure Preview Portal

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, port, azure, docker

I'm trying to open up port 443 on an ubuntu setup using the docker quickstart for wordpress + mysql. Because my VM is classed as "new" it only shows up in the new preview portal on Azure and doesn't show the normal option for creating an endpoint via the usual manage.azure.com interface.

I've tried creating an "inbound security rule" instead to allow access on port 443 but it's still currently closed. Any ideas of how to work around this? Idea is to allow cloudflare flexible ssl (where you don't need an SSL certificate on your server) to work with wordpress.

[image: Preview portal image here.]

Comment: Have you tried changing the inbound rule's source to a tag type (and set the type to Internet)?

Comment: Have just tried that but nmap and other tests say the port is still closed. I've managed to get Cloudflare's flexible SSL working on a wordpress domain mapped site now but did so by editing ports.conf with Listen 443 and also adding a line into iptables. Going to see if I can setup SSL via linux. Is that possible without endpoints or possible to configure outside of portal?